# How do I read the first line of a file using cat?

Tags: bash, file-io, cat

How do I read the first line of a file using `cat`?

Answer (score 601, accepted):

You don't need `cat`.

```
head -1 file
```

will work fine.

Comment: +1. you only need the head not the whole cat :P (the command tail is part of the bash pun too)

Comment: Does `head` read the entire file and cut it, or does it read only the 1 line?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I guess you could check the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/head.c).

Comment: I guess it reads only first lines - it opens a hundreds-megabytes file in milliseconds.

Comment: What about if your were catting multiple files? e.g. I want to achieve `cat file1 file2 | head` without reading all of `file1` and `file2`?

Comment: ...got it! `cat <(head file1) <(head file2)`. [Source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1385/cat-stdout-of-multiple-commands)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a Mac-specific thing, but the command is `head -n 1 file`. There is a `-n` argument to pass the number of lines with.

Comment: `head -1 *.txt` would work too to find first line of all text files

Answer (score 98):

You don't, use `head` instead.

```
head -n 1 file.txt
```

Answer (score 50):

There are many different ways:

```
sed -n 1p file
head -n 1 file
awk 'NR==1' file
```

Comment: And when should we use which?

Answer (score 29):

You could use `cat file.txt | head -1`, but it would probably be better to use head directly, as in `head -1 file.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question!

Answer (score 18):

This may not be possible with `cat`.  Is there a reason you have to use `cat`?

If you simply need to do it with a bash command, this should work for you:

```
head -n 1 file.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

`cat` alone may not be possible, but if you don't want to use `head` this works:

```
 cat <file> | awk 'NR == 1'
```

Comment: I suppose it's silly to call out a 'useless use of cat' on a line specifically designed to use `cat`, isn't it.

Comment: This method is great because you can pick any line you want.

Comment: @desgua `awk` is great, but you don't need `cat` here. `awk 'NR == 2 {print $0}' <file>` does the same thing. (And much more, if you learn a little `awk`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised that this question has been around as long as it has, and nobody has provided the pre-mapfile built-in approach yet.

```
IFS= read -r first_line <file
```

...puts the first line of the file in the variable expanded by `"$first_line"`, easy as that.

Moreover, because `read` is built into bash and this usage requires no subshell, it's significantly more efficient than approaches involving subprocesses such as `head` or `awk`.

Comment: what's the `IFS=` part at the beginning?

Comment: my bad, here is an explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting

Comment: Right; in this case, clearing `IFS` prevents leading and trailing whitespace from being stripped from the string that's read.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need any external command if you have bash v4+

```
< file.txt mapfile -n1 && echo ${MAPFILE[0]}
```

or if you really want `cat`

```
cat file.txt | mapfile -n1 && echo ${MAPFILE[0]}
```

:)

Answer (score 4):

Use the below command to get the first row from a CSV file or any file formats.

```
head -1 FileName.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

There is plenty of good answer to this question. Just gonna drop another one into the basket if you wish to do it with `lolcat`

```sh
lolcat FileName.csv | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding one more obnoxious alternative to the list:

```
perl -pe'$.<=1||last' file
# or 
perl -pe'$.<=1||last' < file
# or
cat file | perl -pe'$.<=1||last'
```