# Checking ELF binary bitness on Android

Tags: android, bash, 32bit-64bit, elf

I'm trying to detect the bitness (32 or 64 bit) of an ELF binary in the bash shell of an android device.

I don't have `file`, `objdump` or `readelf`, which are the obvious answers on a real Linux system.  Additionally, I don't have `head`, `tail`, `sed`, `awk`, `grep` or `perl`.

I've seen in the [ELF header description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) that the `e_ident[EI_CLASS]` field of the binary header should contain a byte which describes the bitness.  Maybe I could use that? But I'm having trouble teasing that byte out of the file with such a limited toolset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

`head -c 20 ${executable} | tail -c 2` will get you the 2 bytes for `e_machine`. Then you can do further processing on that. Eg, x86 may be either 32-bit or 64-bit while x86-64 is 64-bit.

Alternatively, if you're specifically looking for the bitness of the ELF container (as opposed to the executable code), which implies the requirements of the code, you might try looking at `e_ident[EI_CLASS]`:

`head -c 5 ${executable} | tail -c 1`. If the byte is 0x01, it's 32 bit. If it's 0x02, it's 64 bit. If it's anything else, it's undefined at this time.

Edit:
Recommended [read](https://web.archive.org/web/20210808162249/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read)ing (hehe pun intended) describes the difference between `-n` and `-N`.

So without the use of `head` and `tail`, this would be better:
`read -r -N 5 elf_header < ${executable} && echo -n "${elf_header:4:1}"`

At this point, the single character that was echoed to stdout would be `"\\x1"` for 32-bit and `"\\x2"` for 64-bit. In a more complete linux environment you can pass that through `xxd` to see a hex dump. You can check the bit with this 1-liner:

`bitness32=$(printf "\\x1") && bitness64=$(printf "\\x2") && read -r -N 5 elf_header < ~/a.out && elf_bitness="${elf_header:4:1}" && { [[ "${bitness32}" == "${elf_bitness}" ]] && echo "32-bit"; } || { [[ "${bitness64}" == "${elf_bitness}" ]] && echo "64-bit"; } || { echo "???"; }`

Comment: This looks cleaner than the read solution, but I can't rely on my android shell having `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s answer to [How do I read first line using cat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21836990/1567515), I found a way to read only the bytes I needed out of the file:

```
$ # Read 5 bytes of the 'adb' binary.    
$ read -r -n 5 elf_header < /system/bin/adb; echo $elf_header | cat -v
^?ELF^A
```

If the 7th character of that output is "A", then the binary is 32-bit.  If it's "B", then 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Using `printf` and `dd`:

```
#!/bin/sh

elf32="$(printf "\177ELF\001")"
elf64="$(printf "\177ELF\002")"
header="$(dd bs=5 seek=0 count=1 "if=$1" 2> /dev/null)"

case "$header" in
    "$elf32") echo ELF32 ;;
    "$elf64") echo ELF64 ;;
    *)        exit 1 ;;
esac
```